# Let $V$ and $U$ open in $\mathbb{C}$. If $G$ is a component of $V$ and $V \subset U$, then $G$ is connected in $U$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $V$ and $U$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with $V \subset U$ and $\partial  V \cap  U = \varnothing$. If H is a component of U and $H \cap V \neq \varnothing$ then $H \subset V$.

This statement is claimed in Conway's book and is proved, however I do not understand one part of the proof.

So here is that part of the proof:

" Let $a \in H \cap V$ and let $G$ be the component of V such that $a \in G$.
Then $H \cup G$ is connected and contained in $U$. Since $H$ is a component of $U$, then $G \subset H$. "

So I am assuming that when he says $H \cup G$ is connected, he means connected in $U$. However I do not understand why $H \cup G$ is connected in $U$. I know that $H$ is connected in $U$ but how do I know that $G$ is connected in $V$ implies $G$ is connected in $U$?

Comment: $G$ is either connected or not. It doesn't matter if it is "in" another set.

Comment: Then being connected is independent of the metric space?